# Echo all values from mysql column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo all the values of 'comment' from a user defined table (`$table_name`)

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT comment FROM '$table_name'");

    if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {

        $comments = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        foreach ($comments as $comment) {

            $comm = $comment[0];
            echo $comm;

        }
    }
```

However I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object in /FilePath/file.php on line 3

Comment: You have single quotes around the table name.  Remove them.  This is a typographical error and I'm voting to close.

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. This will signal errors found. Plus add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - Not worth putting in an answer for this one. You can fix this once you see the error popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No identifier quotes are **backticks** not single quotes.

```
`backticks`

// not 'table_name'
       ^ single quotes
```

Just take out that quotes. It will work just fine.

```
$stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT comment FROM $table_name");
```

Unless, as @Fred stated, your table name is a [**MySQL reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) or has spaces or a hyphen *(or any other character that SQL will disagree with)*, then you need to have them.

And as always, turn on error reporting.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // below the pdo connection
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// first lines of the file
```

Comment: If OP's table name is called `keys`, or another possible reserved word, then it's best to answer "with" backticks. Let's assume *worse case scenario* ;)

Comment: I also noticed OP is missing `mysql:host=`

Comment: @Fred-ii- that seems to work fine, well, in my env, actually im not aware of that 'til i tested it a while ago when omitting the dsn

Comment: So it's not always needed then?

Comment: @Fred-ii- seems to default to localhost when omitted

Comment: Oh, well I'm going to have to try that out sometime.

Comment: That worked like a charm ,also @Fred-ii- i will make sure to add the mysql:host for future proofing in case I move the database to an external server.

Comment: @LachlanDahlly sure no prob. glad it shed light